# how to add font awesome icons in select options

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to add fontawesome icons in select option.

```
<select name="personList">
   <option *ngFor="let person of personList">{{person.name}}<i class="fa 
       fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Okay. What's the question? Is this not working for you? Throw us a bone here. See [ask].

Comment: When Iam trying to use the above code it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

> icons in select options

You cannot add `i` tags in `option` tags.

Instead you can set the font family on the select to font awesome:

```
select {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome'
}
```

And then use character points for the icon you want e.g. for `fa-user` (http://fontawesome.io/icon/user/):

```
<option>Hi, &#xf007;</option>
```